# Take the first line of the every partition

Tags: sql-server, row-number

I have this query :

```
select   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY codtiers ORDER BY case when isnull(cumulapport, 0) > isnull(cumulretrait, 0) then cumulapport
 else cumulretrait
end DESC ) AS classement,
                    codTiers
           from     dbo.TiersComptesLocal 
           group by codTiers
```

which return this result :

```
classement  |  codTiers  
-------------------------
    1       |  1XXXXX
    2       |  1XXXXX
    1       |  1YYXXX
    2       |  1YYXXX
    3       |  1YYXXX
    1       |  1XXXYY
```

I want to display the first line from every partition
I want to have a result like this :

```
classement  |  codTiers  
-------------------------
    1       |  1XXXXX
    1       |  1YYXXX
    1       |  1XXXYY
```

Any idea will be appreciate.

this is my full query :

```
select   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY tcl_codtiers ORDER BY case when isnull(cumulapport, 0) > isnull(cumulretrait, 0) then cumulapport
                                                                                                                else cumulretrait
                                                                                                           end DESC ) AS classement,

                                        TCL_CodTiers,
                                        'le montant max des ' + Senscumul + ' ( '
                        + convert(varchar(50), '') + ' € ) du tiers titulaire '
                        + TCL_CodTiers + ' ( ' + ''
                        + ' ) est supérieur au seuil fixé dans l''alerte : '
                        + '75000'

                               from     dbo.CLI_TCL_TiersComptesLocal
                                        INNER JOIN dbo.CLI_GCO_GeneriquesComptes ON TCL_CodTiers = GCO_CodTiersPrincipal
                                                                                    AND TCL_NumLien IN ( 0, 1 )
                                                                    inner join ( select TCL_CodTiers CodTiers,
                                                                sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros > 0
                                                                         then ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros
                                                                         else 0
                                                                    end) cumulapport,
                                                                sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros < 0
                                                                         then abs(ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros)
                                                                         else 0
                                                                    end) cumulretrait, 
                                                                      case when isnull(  sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros > 0
                                                                         then ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros
                                                                         else 0
                                                                    end), 0) > isnull( sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros < 0
                                                                         then abs(ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros)
                                                                         else 0
                                                                    end), 0)
                                                 then 'Apports'
                                                 else 'Retraits'
                                            end as Senscumul
                                                         from   CRO_ESO_EntreeSortie
                                                                inner join CLI_TCL_TiersComptesLocal on TCL_CodCompte = ESO_CodCompte
                                                                                                        and TCL_NumLien in ( 0, 1 )
                                                         group by TCL_CodTiers
                                                         having sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros > 0
                                                                         then ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros
                                                                         else 0
                                                                    end) > 75000
                                                                or sum(case when ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros < 0
                                                                            then abs(ESO_MntValoRetenuEnEuros)
                                                                            else 0
                                                                       end) > 75000
                                                       ) surveillance on GCO_CodTiersPrincipal = CodTiers
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codtiers 
                         ORDER BY CASE 
                                    WHEN ISNULL(cumulapport, 0) >
                                         ISNULL(cumulretrait, 0) THEN cumulapport
                                  ELSE cumulretrait
                                  END DESC) AS classement,
                        codTiers
    FROM dbo.TiersComptesLocal 
) 
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE classement = 1;
```

---

### Update

You *can't* filter on that column `classement` in the same query, you have to use a CTE or a subquery instead like in @AaronBertrand  answer. However, if you want to do this in the same query, you have to do this without `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
    SELECT
      codtiers,
      MAX(CASE 
            WHEN ISNULL(cumulapport, 0) >
                 ISNULL(cumulretrait, 0) THEN cumulapport
            ELSE cumulretrait
            END DESC) AS classement
    FROM dbo.TiersComptesLocal 
    GROUP BY codtiers;
```

Comment: I got this error :  Msg 8155, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Aucun nom de colonne n'a été spécifié pour la colonne 3 de 'CTE'.

Comment: @user1805523 It said that there is a column that you select with out a name inside the `CTE` each column selected inside the cTE has to be named. Please post the full query you tried.

Comment: I'm asking if there are a solution that allows to use the alias "classement"directly in the where clause (ie without using WITH)

Comment: @user1805523 No there is not using the `ROW_Number()`. But you can without the rownumber, I will  updated my answer, by another solution without `ROW_NUMBER()`.

Comment: @user1805523 why can't you use `WITH`? Because you're getting syntax errors?

Comment: No, I have to retrieve another solution without using WITH

Comment: @user1805523 yes, you said that, but can you explain WHY?

Comment: Please don't post a query in the comment. If you have additional information or clarification of requirements, add it to the question.

Comment: this is the statement of the exercise requires

Comment: @user1805523 the exercise says you can't use a CTE? What kind of exercise is this? One in futility?

Comment: I added the full query in my question..I still got the same error

Answer (score 2):

No idea why you don't want to use a CTE, but you can use a derived table if you want, though it still is basically the same answer that Mahmoud already posted:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codtiers 
                                ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(cumulapport, 0)>ISNULL(cumulretrait, 0) 
                                              THEN cumulapport ELSE cumulretrait END DESC) AS classement,
             codTiers
        FROM dbo.TiersComptesLocal 
        GROUP BY codTiers) A
WHERE classement = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution without using `WITH` - though I'm not sure why that is a problem.

```
SELECT classement, codtiers
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    classement = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY codtiers 
      ORDER BY CASE WHEN ISNULL(cumulapport, 0) > ISNULL(cumulretrait, 0) 
      THEN cumulapport ELSE cumulretrait END DESC),
    codTiers
  FROM dbo.TiersComptesLocal 
) AS x
WHERE classement = 1;
```